# Alternate page with proper canonical tag - htaccess rule

Tags: google-search-console, htaccess

I have been receiving lots of canonical error messages from Google Search Console.  Most of the time, the referring pages are my own pages and the urls are correct in the referring page.

Google is indicating that the errors are destination urls without a trailing slash.  I.e, `example.com/mypage` vs `example.com/mypage/`  However, my permalink structure in WordPress is set to end all urls with a trailing slash.  The user declared canonicals are also using trailing slashes according to the page source and Google.

I think the problem is with my htaccess file and a WordPress plugin that has enabled https rewrites. My current htaccess rewrite rule is below.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm not a regular expression or htaccess expert, but if I want my permalinks to all end with a slash shouldn't this be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I.e., shouldn't there be a "/" after the $1?

**Edit**
If I type in `http:example.com/mypage` in the address bar, it still redirects to `https://example.com/mypage/`.

**Plugin Rewrite section (comes first in htaccess file):**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Wordpress Rewrite section (comes later in htaccess file):**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Note:**  After looking at my network tab (as MrWhite suggested) I see only one 301 redirect (not two).  I.e., `http://example.com/mypage` is redirected to `https://example.com/mypage` without the trailing slash.  Additionally, if I use `https://example.com/mypage` it redirects to `https://example.com/mypage` without the trailing slash as well even though the url is identical.

Mr White, you are correct, I am using Cloudflare and my SSL is set to strict on Cloudflare.

**Request/Reponse Headers:**

```
GET /mypage HTTP/2
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
...
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
...
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
TE: trailers

HTTP/2 301 Moved Permanently
...
location: https://example/mypage/
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains;preload
...
x-redirect-by: WordPress
...
server: cloudflare
...
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Comment: Is the redirect from `/mypage` to `/mypage/` triggered by a rule in `.htaccess` or by WordPress? Check the network traffic to make sure there is not a (lengthy/incorrect) redirect chain. (Although if the redirect to append the trailing is performed by WP then you would see 2 redirects... the first to HTTPS and the second to append the trailing slash. But this is not necessarily wrong.)

Comment: "if I use `https://example.com/mypage` it redirects to `https://example.com/mypage` without the trailing slash as well even though the url is identical." - Are you actually seeing an external 3xx redirect? What is the HTTP status? What are the HTTP response headers on these requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

There's nothing wrong with this rule. (Although it's not complete by itself. I assume there must be a `RewriteCond` directive that precedes this that checks the `HTTPS` status.)

The purpose of this rule is to simply redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, preserving the same URL-path (and hostname) as requested. Yes, it would redirect `http://example.com/mypage` to `https://example.com/mypage`. But it also redirects `http://example.com/mypage/` to `https://example.com/mypage/`. If you simply appended a trailing slash to the *substitution* string then it would redirect `/mypage/` to `/mypage//` - which would not be good.

If you wanted to redirect from no-trailing-slash to trailing-slash in `.htaccess` then this should be implemented as a separate rule. This rule can also redirect to HTTPS in order to potentially avoid multiple redirects when the HTTP version of the URL (without a trailing slash) is requested - but this should be an *edge* case.

The problem is unlikely to be in the `.htaccess` file, unless there is a redirect that *removes* the trailing slash - although that does not seem to be the case.

You need to make sure that:

1. All your internal links point to the canonical URL *with* a trailing slash.
2. All links in the sitemap reference the canonical URL.
3. All `rel="canoncial"` elements reference the canonical URL. (As you mentioned.)

Maybe the GSC error is historical? Did you previously use URLs *without* a trailing slash?

Also check the network traffic for any redirect chains. Whilst the destination URL contains the trailing slash, maybe there is an intermediary redirect that removes it?!

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite.  I added more details from my htaccess file to the OP and I checked the Network tab for multiple redirects.  I'm only seeing an initial redirect in my browser.  It's redirecting to https without the trailing slash, but then the next line is 200 with the trailing slash, so I'm not really sure how WordPress is adding the slash as I thought it was via htaccess.

Comment: @Trebor It would seem you are using Cloudflare? Do you have any page rules defined? CF can also be configured to redirect HTTP to HTTPS (no need for `.htaccess`). Please update your question with the HTTP response headers for each request. Specifically, what are the `Location` and `Server` headers in these responses?

Comment: Thank you.  I think you've located the problem.  I did migrate to Cloudflare, and recently turned on Strict SSL.  I would not have thought that my WP, my plugin and Cloudflare were causing the problem together.  Am I to assume then that if I remove the SSL redirect added by my plugin, and leave Cloudflare in place with SSL, this should solve the redirect?  Thanks.  BTW, how did you recognize Cloudflare usage from my post?